# Angular universal SSR 16, first call to find user's ip went from server instead of client?

Tags: server-side-rendering, ip-address, angular-universal, angular16, angular-ssr

I want to retrieve the client's browser IP address when running an Angular SSR application. In Angular 16, do I need to use **provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)**?

Here, Is the code I have tried. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqajY.png)

I couldn't locate a reference for **provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)**.

Without using **provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)** IP address is returning as null. So How to do it in angular 16 SSR?